# Data not entered into database from PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I am trying to enter data into a database with PHP.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $username = 'username'; //username for database
    $password = 'password'; //password for database
    $hostname = 'localhost'; //host
    $db_name =  'db_testdrubin'; //name of database

    $db_selected = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name)//specify database
    or die ("unable to connect");

    if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){
        $ID = ($_POST['ID']);
        $fname = ($_POST['fname']);
        $lname = ($_POST['lname']);
        $address = ($_POST['address']);
        $city = ($_POST['city']);
        $state = ($_POST['state']);
        $zip = ($_POST['zip']);
        $phone = ($_POST['phone']);
        $email = ($_POST['email']);
        $books = ($_POST['books[]']);
        $comments = ($_POST['comments']);
    }
    else{
        echo'<p>not submitted</p>';
    }
    //up until this point the code works fine

    $query = 'INSERT INTO Student VALUES ($ID, $fname, $lname, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $email, $books, $comments)';


    $success = $db_selected->query($query);

    if($success){
        $count = $db_selected->affectd_rows;
        echo '<p>$count were added</p>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<p>error</p>';
    }

?>
```

I know that the information is being read from the html form correctly because I have checked by printing the individual variables. I am not getting any error messages when I submit the form, just the "error" echo statement from the if/else statement, and no data is entered into the database.

I have also tried this:

```
if (!mysql_query($db_selected, $query)){
    echo '<p>error</p>';
}
```

with the same results.

Comment: NEVER output a pointless fixed unchanging "Error" message, especially when mysql can TELL you what the problem is: `echo mysql_error();` instead. Given the way you're building the insert query, it's one massive syntax error, and a massive SQL Injection attack vulnerability as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO Student VALUES ($ID, $fname, $lname, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $phone, $email, $books, $comments)';
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Student VALUES ($ID, '$fname', '$lname', '$address', '$city', '$state', $zip, $phone, '$email', '$books', '$comments')";
```

I mean to say if its string then do like '$string' and also use

```
$db_selected->real_escape_string($stringval);
```

and use

```
echo $db_selected->error;
```

to check the error you got.

Comment: OK, I see now that my error is in the query statement itself. I'm going to try to figure out where the error is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to add `echo $db_selected->error;` That told me exactly where my error was in the insert statement. My code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ins="insert into Student (`id`,`fname`,`lname`,`address`,`city`,`state`,`zip`,`phone`,`email`,`books`,`comments`)values
  ('".$ID."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$address."','".$city."','".$state."','".$zip."','".$phone."','".$email."','".$books."','".$comments."')"; 

mysql_query($ins);
```